# How to push data coming from setInterval into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, redux

My setInterval function should inject data into an array. It is object -- `{id: 0}` and then `{id:1}{id:2}`...--to be injected and the value of id changes after every timeout has fired. But instead of populating it into an array in order to get something like `[{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}...]` I'm getting still the same value `[{id:1}]`. I'm using push function:

```
const arr = [];
arr.push(this.props.test);
console.log(arr);
```

`this.props.test` is just new object after setInterval fires every time. Contrary to my expectations I'm getting always last object in my console.log.

Comment: if you declare a new `arr` every time (which seems to be the case from the 3 lines of "code" you posted, that doesn't even include a `setInterval` at all), then yes, there will be exactly one entry every time you console.log - perhaps, show a minimal but complete and verifiable example of code if you need help

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get you right, you need something like this:

```js
const arr = [];
let counter = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  arr.push({id: counter++});
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
}, 2000);
```

**Explanation:** the first parameter of the `setInterval` is a function that is executed every 2 seconds. In this function you create a new object `{id: counter++}` and push it to your array. Note that you need to create the array outside of `setInterval` - otherwise it will be overwritten

Comment: Please add some explanation for providing a real help.

Comment: @Barth You're welcome! If my answer helped, please accept it

Answer (score 0):

My guess, you may put the code ‘const arr = []’ in the callback function of setInterval. That’s making the array arr get initialized to nothing every time the interval comes.  So when you console.log the arr, it always prints out only the last time the object your code pushed. 
You need to put the code ‘const arr = []’ outside of callback function of setInterval.

May it helps. Good luck.